# How to make a discord bot leave the voice channel after being inactive for 5 minutes?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make code that make bot left after 5 minutes of inactivity. Like that the bot left if user is not playing song for 5 min

```
@client.command()
async def play(ctx, *, url):
    voicetrue = ctx.guild.me.voice
    if voicetrue is None:
        await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()

    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    if not player:
        player = music.create_player(ctx, ffmpeg_error_betterfix=True)
    if not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
        await player.queue(url, search=True)
        song = await player.play()
        title = 'Igram!'
        desc = f'Igram: `{song.name}` \n \n  Ogledi: `{song.views}` \n Trajanje: `{song.duration}` '
        embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=desc, color=discord.Colour.red())
        url = song.thumbnail
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        

    else:
        song = await player.queue(url, search=True)
        await ctx.send(f'{song.name} is Queued')



@client.command()
async def volume(ctx, vol):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song, volume = await player.change_volume(float(vol) / 100)



    embed=discord.Embed(title = 'Glasnost',
    description = (f'Glasnost je spremenjena za `{song.name}` v `{volume*100}%`'))
    url = song.thumbnail
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
      

   
    

@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()

    embed=discord.Embed(title='Glasba', description='LucBot se je uspesno joinal!')
    embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/868844233228972052/869606994846310400/PicsArt_07-27-05.45.02.png')





    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This is my code right now ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: you need to define what is inactive

Comment: i did.. if person dont play song for 5 minutes

Comment: save a timestamp of when the last song was played then have a [task.loop](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) that will check if the time passed every ten seconds or so then leave your client from the voice